# React error: TypeError: render is not a function

Tags: reactjs

I am getting an error that says "TypeError: render is not a function"

Here is the details:

updateContextConsumer

.../React/contextapi/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:18747

```
  18744 | {
  18745 |   ReactCurrentOwner$1.current = workInProgress;
  18746 |   setIsRendering(true);
> 18747 |   newChildren = render(newValue);
        | ^  18748 |   setIsRendering(false);
  18749 | } // React DevTools reads this flag.
  18750 |
```

View compiled

beginWork

.../React/contextapi/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:19114

```
  19111 |   return updateContextProvider(current, workInProgress, renderLanes);
  19112 | 
  19113 | case ContextConsumer:
> 19114 |   return updateContextConsumer(current, workInProgress, renderLanes);
        | ^  19115 | 
  19116 | case MemoComponent:
  19117 |   {
```

View compiled

I have the following code in **Navbar.js**:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { ThemeContext } from '../contexts/ThemeContext';
 
class Navbar extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <ThemeContext.Consumer> { context => 
            {
                const { isDarkTheme, darkTheme, lightTheme } = context;
                const theme = isDarkTheme ? darkTheme : lightTheme;
 
                return (
                    <nav style={‌{ background: theme.background, color: theme.text, height: '120px' }}>
                        <h2 style={‌{ textAlign: 'center' }}>
                            Oak Academy
                        </h2>
                        <div className="ui three buttons">
                            <button className="ui button">Overview</button>
                            <button className="ui button">Contact</button>
                            <button className="ui button">Support</button>
 
                        </div>
                    </nav>
                )
            }}
            </ThemeContext.Consumer>
        );
    }
}
 
export default Navbar;
```

On **ThemeContext.js** I have the following code:

```
import React, { Component, createContext } from 'react'
 
export const ThemeContext = createContext();
 
class ThemeContextProvider extends Component {
    state = {
        isDarkTheme: true,
        lightTheme: {
            text: '#222',
            background: '#d8ddf1'
        },
        darkTheme: {
            text: '#fff',
            background: '#5c5c5c'
        }
    }
 
    //... <-gets all properties
    render() {
        return (
            <ThemeContext.Provider value={‌{ ...this.state }}>
                {this.props.children}
            </ThemeContext.Provider>
        );
    }
}
 
export default ThemeContextProvider;
```

I have tried googling this error message, but all I could find is a bit of a typo, but I tried to see if there way worked, but it did not help. How could I fix this issue?

Comment: Just a quick update, I did notice something strange about this code though. I was watching a tutorial on this and just noticed that  I have two `return()` here in `Navbar.js`. Not sure if this is acceptable or not.

Comment: Your returns look fine, they belong to two different components. Can you create a reproducible example on jsfiddle or similar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is most likely the whitespace in this line:

```
  <ThemeContext.Consumer> { context =>
```

The space before the `{` is parsed as a React child, so the children passed to `ThemeContext.Consumer` are an array containing the string `' '` and your function. You can either remove the space or put `{ context =>` on a newline, so all whitespace gets stripped.

Comment: Wow, I did not know having a white space would affect react at all.